# Still learning Python, having to create a GUI for temperature conversion, buttons do not work, nor fields

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The project is a GUI-based program that allows the user to convert a value between Fahrenheit and Celsius. At start-up the Fahrenheit field should read "32.0" and the Celsius field should read "0.0"  Below the Fahr. input field should be a button labeled ">>>>" and when clicked, should convert to Celsius. The button below the Cels. field should be labeled "<<<<" to convert to Fahrenheit. And the row below that should contain the descriptions for the buttons. I have the computations, and the widget made, mostly. However I can not get the fields to read 32.0 and 0.0 upon start-up instead of 0.0 and 0.0. Nor do the buttons function. Bare in mind, I'm only in my 9th week of Python classes but I am stuck on this one part.
Here is the code, and the current window.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class _TemperatureConversion(Frame):

def __init__(self):
     #Sets up the window and widget
     Frame.__init__(self)
     self.master.title("Temperature Conversion")
     self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight = 5)
     self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 5)
     self.master.geometry("300x300")
     self.master.resizable(0,0)
     self.grid(rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1)

    # Calculates the Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion
     font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Arial Black", size = 15)
     self._fahrLabel = Label(self, font = font, text = " Fahrenheit ")
     self._fahrLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
     self._fahrVar = DoubleVar()
     font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 13)
     self._FahrValue = Entry(self, font = font, fg = "blue", justify =      "center", width = 13,
                            textvariable = self._fahrVar, text = "32.0",)
     self._FahrValue.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

     # Calculates the Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion
     font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Arial Black", size = 15)
     self._celsLabel = Label(self, font = font, text = " Celsius ")
     self._celsLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
     self._celsVar = DoubleVar()
     font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 13)
     self._CelsValue = Entry(self, font = font, fg = "red", justify = "center", width = 13,
                                 textvariable = self._celsVar)
     self._CelsValue.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

     # The command buttons
     self._button = Button(self, font = font,
                           text = " >>>> ",
                           command = self._FahrValueN)
     font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 15)
     self._button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 1)

     self._button = Button(self, font = font,
                           text = " <<<< ",
                           command = self._CelsValue)
     font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 15)
     self._button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 1)

     #### From here down is not to be indented
     #### Just indented to keep it in the window

def _fahrenheitToCelsius(FahrValue):
    Fahr = FahrValue
    Cels = ((Fahr - 32) * 5) / 9
    print(Cels)

def _celsiusToFahrenheit(CelsValue):
     Cels = CelsValue
     Fahr = ((Cels * 9) / 5) + 32
     print(Fahr)

def main():
    _TemperatureConversion().mainloop()
    FahrValue = float(input("Enter a Fahrenheit value to convert: "))
    FConvert = fahrenheitToCelsius(FahrValue)
    CelsValue = float(input("Enter a Celsius value to convert: "))
    CConvert = celsiusToFahrenheit(CelsValue)

main()
```

Comment: your code is not entirely well formatted. Also maybe you can put less code as your question is only on the initial value of the field?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `textvariable`  assigned to the Fahrenheit field, so just set the `DoubleVar`:

```
self._fahrVar.set(32.0)
```

After that, you want to rename your methods, as there don't exist methods named `_FahrValueN` or `_CelsValue`. If you want to update the entries, you just have to update the variables:

```
def fahrenheitToCelsius(self):
    Fahr = self._fahrVar.get()
    self._celsVar.set(((Fahr - 32) * 5) / 9)
```

It's rather strange in your `main()` function to have another input there that runs only when the GUI is closed. You might want to remove that. Additionally, wrap the function call like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This avoids the main function being called when the module is imported.